# How to calculate the \$\mathcal{H}_2\$ norm of a second order transfer function?

Tags: control, control-system

I'm having trouble to calculate the \$\mathcal{H}_2\$ norm of a second order transfer function

$$H(s) = \frac{\omega_n^2}{s^2+2\xi\omega_ns+\omega_n^2}$$
where \$\xi>0\$ and \$\omega_n>0\$. I know that the \$\mathcal{H}_2\$ norm is given by
$$||H_2|| = \bigg\{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|H(j\omega)|^2d\omega\bigg\}^{1/2}$$
and that the magnitude of the frequency response is given by
$$|H(j\omega)| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\bigg(\dfrac{2\xi\omega}{\omega_n}\bigg)^2+\bigg(1-\dfrac{\omega^2}{\omega_n^2}\bigg)^2}}$$
Can someone help me with this? Is there another away to calculate it?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please provide an attempt at a solution

Comment: That's the only way I know. The H2 norm is a scalar positive number and it is the Hilbert's length of vector H.

Comment: You can use parseval's relation and try to integrate in time domain , it should be easy for $$\xi>=1$$but for$$0<\xi<1$$ it would be messy !

Comment: @MissMulan Cross posting is not appropriate https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: Are you trying to derive \$|H(j\omega)|\$ from \$H(s)\$ of a 2nd order low pass filter?

Comment: This norm looks similar to \$L^2\$ norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a state-space representation, the \$H_2\$ norm can be computed as \$\sqrt{\text{Trace}\left(b q b^T\right)}\$ or \$\sqrt{\text{Trace}\left(c p c^T\right)}\$, where \$b\$ and \$c\$ are the input and output matrices, and \$q\$ and \$p\$ are the observability and controllability gramians.

I have done the calculations below using Mathematica and the result is \$\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\omega _n}{\zeta }}\$.

[image]